# What is this word (audio)

Tags: word, audio

https://youtu.be/i_BYzgl3yEo at 0:46 or at 0:59 a person in background screams out something like "lalatije." What is that word and how its written?

Comment: 來了，老爹！ (I'm coming, pops!) I don't know the context, sounds like he's coming to rescue whoever he calls 老爹 (pops/grandpa/daddy).

Comment: @droooze Might as well make it an answer then.

Comment: @user3306356 Was waiting on someone who plays LoL to understand the context of the game and make a better answer. Maybe there's a Champion in LoL called 老爹, I've never played the game haha...

Comment: 来了，老弟儿！(Come, dude!)An exclamation when the Steam Golem BLITZ grabbed an enemy

Comment: @TooskyHierot 啊，難道我把“老弟兒”聽成了“老爹”。。。。。。

Comment: 来了, 老弟 is a Chinese meme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 来了，老弟儿！ It sounds like 老爹er in some way(due to the accent of the speaker). It means ***Here you come, buddy!***.

Comment: I found the translation from the same guy in another video who uploads and translates videos from that streamer and his partner. In translation sub-text "Láile, lǎo diē" meant "Here they come by bro".